# number to Qstring with precision

Tags: c++, qt, converters, qstring

I want to convert floating point number to Qstring object. When number is -0.001 and i set precition 2, it return -0.00 but want 0.00.
How to remove minus sign for this situation ?

Comment: "integer number"? you meant floating point!

Comment: and where is your code which is faulty almost for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Pick whichever you like:

```
const double d = -0.001;

qDebug() << QString::number(int(d*100) / 100.0, 'f', 2);
qDebug() << QString::number(qRound(d*100) / 100.0, 'f', 2);
qDebug() << QString::number(qRound64(d*100) / 100.0, 'f', 2);
```

Comment: But what to do to have mehtod which let save any double with any precision to QString object?
Like for example I hava a double ``d``, and want to save it into QString ``s`` with precision ``n``.